Trying to push to the repo in a CI job but getting "stale data" and "branch tip is behind its remote"
I'm trying to have a CI job make changes to a file then push those changes back up to the repo. I'm following recommendations from this answer. This is what my job looks like:
changelog:
  stage: release
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 100
  before_script:
    - git config user.name "$GITLAB_USER_NAME"
    - git config user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
    - git remote remove $CI_PROJECT_NAME || true
    - git remote add $CI_PROJECT_NAME  https://oauth2:$CI_ACCESS_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_FQDN/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
  script:
    - < make my changes >
    - git add .
    - git commit --amend --no-edit
    - git push $CI_PROJECT_NAME  HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH -o ci.skip --dry-run --force-with-lease

Without --force-with-lease I was getting this error:

Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote

After adding that, there's no error message returned except this:

[rejected]        HEAD -> my-branch (stale info)

These CI jobs obviously are running on the newest commit on the branch--why when the CI job makes a local commit would it think that it's behind the remote?
How do I get this working?

GIT_DEPTH -> GIT_STRATEGY: clone

The job runs a script to update the changelog. That script gets different info like tags, git log, etc. I tried GIT_STRATEGY: clone and it can't some of that info. I switched from git push ... --force-with-lease to git push ... --force and it's working, but from what I've heard isn't using --force bad practice?

Och there is git commit amend. You are changing git history - rewritting last commit. Why would you do that? It will result in a constant pain from developers. It is bad practice, as in shouldn't be used normally at all. As it is your pipeline is now, try to work with it and push few commits and see what happens and see why it is bad for you when you have git history full of merges or rebases. How do you intend to synchronize local git with remote? Push two separate commits, let pipeline run two times. A commit can dissapear, it's a race condition, and good luck synchronizing.

Ok thanks for the advice. I'm trying to automate my release process, which is effectively: dev creates /release commit > CI pipeline generates changelog & commits > Run GPG sign in repo & commit > create tag > create release. I'm trying to do all this in one CI pipeline, which is the reason for the amend. Otherwise its commit > pipeline 1 > commit > pipeline 2 etc etc. Not sure what the best strategy is

which is the reason for the amend is it a eason to amend? Why amend? Amend will also trigger a pipeline, it's a new commit, so new pipeline. Doing "in one pipeline" is not a reason for rewriting history. Add ci.skip to git push to skip ci if you want.
